# Random binary matrix with row and column sum constraints

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

My objective is to create:

- a randomly populated matrix with entries either `0` or `1`. In this particular case, the matrix is `4x24`.
- The row sum of each of the `4` rows is exactly `6`.
- The column sum of each of the `24` columns is exactly `1`

Call the desired matrix `M`.

Another way of looking at `M`:

- There are exactly `24` entries equal to `1`.
- No column has more than one `1` entry.

Progress:

There are `6` spots on each row with a `1` entry.  The rest are zero, the matrix is sparse. With `4` rows, this means that M can be uniquely determined by a matrix of *indices* that stores the *locations* of the `1` entries. Call this matrix of indices `indexM`.

I populated `indexM` with the numbers `1:24` sampled without replacement:

```
set.seed(30592)
colNum <- 24
rowSum <-6
numZeros <- colNum-rowSum

OneRow<-c(rep(1,rowSum),rep(0,numZeros))


indexM<-matrix(sample(1:24,replace=FALSE),
                    nrow=4,ncol=6,byrow=TRUE)
```

For the given seed, the matrix is: https://pastebin.com/8T21MiDv .

How do I turn `indexM` into the desired sparse matrix?

I found the `sparseMatrix` in the `Matrix` library, but it wants a vector or row indices and another vector of column indices, which is not what I have.

Thank you.

Comment: `sparseMatrix(rep(1:4, each=6), sample(24))` seems to be it, pretty directly from reading `?sparseMatrix`..?

Comment: @Frank that's `i` and `j`? If you can explain the syntax in an answer that would be fantastic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I found the `sparseMatrix` in the `Matrix` library, but it wants a vector or row indices and another vector of column indices, which is not what I have.

The constraints impose that...

- row indices are `rep(1:4, 6)`
- col indices are `1:24`

The match between row and col indices is randomized. We can...

```
library(Matrix)

# fix rows, jumble cols
sparseMatrix(rep(1:4, each=6), sample(1:24))

# fix cols, jumble rows
sparseMatrix(sample(rep(1:4, each=6)), 1:24)

# jumbl'm all
sparseMatrix(sample(rep(1:4, each=6)), sample(1:24))
```

any of which will return something like

```
4 x 24 sparse Matrix of class "ngCMatrix"

[1,] . . . . | | . . | . . . | | . | . . . . . . . .
[2,] . | | . . . | . . | . . . . . . . . | . . . | .
[3,] . . . | . . . | . . | | . . . . | . . . | . . .
[4,] | . . . . . . . . . . . . . | . . | . | . | . |
```