# How to find the exact matrix only composed with 0 and 1 when the sum of each column and row were known

Tags: r, matrix

I want to find the exact matrix only composed with 0 and 1 when the sum of each column and row were known. For example, as shown in the picture blow,the sum of each column and row were known,how to find the exact matrix satisfied . The elements of the matrix can only be 0 or 1.
Here are the sum of columns and rows,and the length of column and row isn't equal.

`col_sum <- c(3,3,4,4,5,5,4)

row_sum <- c(6,5,4,4,3,3,3,0)`

[an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q35y2.png)

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us where you're running into problems?

Comment: Please don't show data as a screenshot. Make your question reproducible by (1) including data in a copy&paste-able format using `dput`, (2) include your code attempt and describe what failed and how, and (3) include your expected output for the sample data you give.

Comment: Multiple binary matrices can be defined by the row and column sums. Do you want all of them?

Comment: @C. Braun Are there any function or package can do that?

Comment: the title looks so similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593877/random-binary-matrix-with-row-and-column-sum-constraints

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not necessarily unique; however, we can find one of the possibly multiple solutions using linear programming.  First set up a test case.

```
library(lpSolve)

# test data
set.seed(123)
n <- 4
m <- matrix(sample(0:1, n*n, replace = TRUE), n)
cs <- colSums(m)
rs <- rowSums(m)

# solve using linear programming
obj <- numeric(n*n)
const.mat <- rbind(t(rep(1, n) %x% diag(n)), t(diag(n) %x% rep(1, n)))
const.rhs <- c(rs, cs)
res <- lp("min", obj, const.mat, "=", const.rhs, all.bin = TRUE)
soln <- matrix(res$solution, n)

# check that row and column totals of soln are correct
all.equal(c(rowSums(soln), colSums(soln)), c(rs, cs))
## [1] TRUE
```

### Example from question

```
col_sum <- c(3,3,4,4,5,5,4)
row_sum <- c(6,5,4,4,3,3,3,0)

# solve using linear programming
m <- length(row_sum)
n <- length(col_sum)
obj <- numeric(m*n)
const.mat <- rbind(t(rep(1, n) %x% diag(m)), t(diag(n) %x% rep(1, m)))
const.rhs <- c(row_sum, col_sum)
res <- lp("min", obj, const.mat, "=", const.rhs, all.bin = TRUE)
soln <- matrix(res$solution, m)

# check that row and column totals of soln are correct
all.equal(c(rowSums(soln), colSums(soln)), c(row_sum, col_sum))
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. if t the length of column and row isn't equal. how to define `diag(n)` . I have uploaded the sum of columns and rows above.